# Proving Fibonacci sequence with combinatorics and binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Disclaimer: This is a school assignment so please don't give me the answer right away.

Let $S$ be the set of binary strings where any block of $0$'s must be followed by a block of $1$'s of greater length, and let $a_{n}$ be the number of strings in $S$ of length $n$. Prove that for $n\geq1, a_{n}=f_{n}$ where $\{f_{n}\}$ is the Fibonacci sequence. 
(Hint: Use the set $M=\{01,0011, 0000111,...\}$, and modify the block decomposition.

I am having trouble to even start the question, especially the "let $a_{n}$ be the number of strings in $S$ of length $n$".

Can someone lead by just giving me some examples of $a_{n}$? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing out the strings of length $1,2,3, \dots$ contained in $S$? Any ways to generate such strings using words in $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, here are the qualifying strings in $S$ for some low values of $n$:

\begin{array}{r|c|c}
n=1 & 2& 3 & 4 & 5\\ \hline
1 & 11 & 111 & 1111 & 11111 \\
& & 011 & 1011 & 11011\\
& & & 0111 & 10111\\
& & & & 01111 \\
& & & & 00111 \\
\end{array}

I have ordered the sets in a way that might be helpful...

Comment: Thanks for your help. So what would $a_{n}$ be in each case? Is it the same as n?

Comment: @HarBear The value of $a_n$ is the number of entries in the corresponding $n$ column: $1,1,2,3,5,...$